# How can I fix a OneScreen it has the message; touch event have been locked? so I can't use the touch screen

Tags: events, touch, screen, locked

by mistake The message "touch event have been blocked" appeared when I pressed the Onescreen's menu button, preventing me from using the touch-screen mode.

I have reset the Onescreen, but the touch screen function still performs better.